# Overcome NA's in Random Forest and SVM?

Tags: r, machine-learning, missing-data, data-imputation

I am using clinical data for prediction purposes with SVM and RF. Two of my columns are as following:

```
 Previous_Surgery     Years_since_previous_surgery
    Yes                            5
    Yes                            16 
    Yes                            9 
    No                             NA
    No                             NA
```

According to literature the time from last surgery is an extremely relevant factor determining if a new surgery will be needed. The problem, is that if someone has never had a surgery we obtain NA's in the years from previous surgery. If I use caret and randomForest package in R, these NA rows are ommitted.

Expressing in a numeric fashion is paramount and at this stage I don't consider using factors. 
How could I overcome this problem? Expressing the NA's with a 0? (I don't think it is a good idea though). Can I force caret to use these observations somehow?

**EDIT**

Data Imputation for this problem is completely wrong and illogical. If we did so we would have something like: Previous_surgery==No and Years_since_previous_surgery==8 for instance. This is not feasible and illogical. Thus the question is more a matter of how I could express those NA in a fashion that I can use them for prediction purposes without adding distortions.

Comment: I think you are going to have to give us more detail about the data-set and the clinical question which you are trying to answer.

Comment: Have you considered using the "mice" package which, as Sycorax indicates, is part of a deep/delicious field of stats called "missing data imputation".

Comment: @Sycorax of course I know what data imputation is but this is not what I need for this problem. As you can see, both columns are correlated in the sense that if someone didn't have a previous surgery there can't be data on the years_since_previous_surgery as he has never had a surgery. Thus data imputation would be completely wrong as those NA's would be filled in with estimations e.g. Previous surgery == No and Years_since_previous_surgery == 7 which is absolutely illogical and wrong.

Comment: Interesting problem! I agree that imputation is unhelpful here. I don't have a complete solution, but it might help if you defined a separate binary variable indicating *whether* they had ever had a previous surgery. As for the NAs in this column, instead of replacing them with zeroes, you could consider using a value *higher* than all others in the dataset. Since you are using a tree-based approach, either coding method might work, though.

Comment: Ah, I see. We get a lot of questions about missing data and random forest where the answer *is* “try imputation,” so I jumped the gun in this case. Just use an RF implementation that treats NA as their own category: at each split, the model examines if putting NA to the left or the right improves model fit. Or just fill in a numerical value that is unique to NA and use both columns together, since they both together represent “state”.